# Command to assert the current HEAD points to master?

Tags: git

I want a command that will fail (with code 1) unless the HEAD points at master.

This kind of works:

```
git diff master --quiet || (echo 'Not master' && false)
```

But it's too strict – it also fails if there are any uncommitted changes in the working tree.

How can I assert that `HEAD` points at `master`, discounting any unstaged or uncommitted changes in the working tree?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Considering that HEAD can point directly to a commit (detached head) or point to some branch that happens to match with the content of commit at the tip of master, comparing it using diff will not be 100% accurate. On the other hand, the HEAD is just a file containing a symbolic reference, [according to docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrepository-layout#gitrepository-layout-HEAD), which could be compared directly.

```
test "$(cat "$(git rev-parse --git-path HEAD)")" == "ref: refs/heads/master"
```

Or

```
test "$(cat "$(git rev-parse --git-path HEAD)")" == "ref: refs/heads/master" && echo "HEAD points to master" || echo "HEAD does not point to master"
```

Comment: Similar approach (assuming `bash`) without need for nested command substitution:
`[[ $(git symbolic-ref HEAD) == refs/heads/master ]]`

Comment: Note that `git symbolic-ref HEAD` will fail (exit nonzero and print a message to stderr) if `HEAD` is detached. Presumably the OP wants this.  The `cat` of located `HEAD` trick works without having to account for this, but calling `git symbolic-ref` is the formally-correct method (theoretically future-proof in case someone changes the way `HEAD` works someday).

Answer (score 2):

Check the exit code of this command:

```
git branch | grep "* master"
```

Comment: Nice, but I had to change it to `git branch --color=never | grep '* master'` because I've got color enabled in my global git config, and this screws up the grep.

Comment: @callum Why does the color screw up the grep?

Answer (score 1):

You can compare with `HEAD`:

```
git diff HEAD master --quiet || (echo 'Not master' && false)
```

If you want to allow empty commits:

```
[ $(git show --oneline HEAD..master master..HEAD | wc -l) -eq 0] || (echo 'Not master' && false)
```

Or:

```
[ "$(git rev-parse HEAD)" = "$(git rev-parse master)" ] || (echo 'Not master' && false)
```